# How to single out the first bit and retaining the last bit of the filename using grep(find)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Greeting

I am writing a bash code to convert decimal to binary from a file name (Ex: `023-124.grf`) and unfortunately, I only need to only convert the last 3 numbers of the file without interfering with the first bit
(it looks something like this: `124.grf`)
I had already tried using cut but it is only ethical with a text file and as for grepping, i am still trying to figure out on using this command since I am still relatively new to bash
Is there a way to single out the first bit of the filename?

Comment: What do you mean by "bit"? "part"? Or "binary digit"? It is quite ambiguous given the context (convert decimal to binary).

Comment: Plus, you seems to be focused only on file name (tho in some part of the question you say "file"). In which case, it doesn't matter whether the file is a text file or not, since you are not dealing at all with its content. The file name is always a text, and that is all that matter. I mean ``$(echo "023-124.grf" | cut -d "-" -f2)``  is "124.grf" without any consideration about the content of that file (nor even its existence. ``023-124.grf`` is just a string here. The fact that this string happens to be a file name is irrelevant to this computation)

Comment: So, those confusion between "file name" and "file", the fact that you seem to worry about the file not being a text one... all that makes me wonder if I understand your question correctly. May be you should clarify, by showing what you've tried.

Comment: Last remark: I've used ``cut`` in my previous comment, because you've mentioned it. But a more pure bash way to do what my cut command does would be ``${filename#*-}``, that is the filename minus everything that is before the dash.

Comment: Not sure I understand the ethics of renaming.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure you completely specified your problem, but luckily, even a very general variation of it can be solved fairly easily, considering that grep allows you to match both digit and non-digit characters.

So to match "the last 3 consecutive digits that are not succeeded by a digit" in any text (even if it looks like "234_blablabla_lololol_343123_blablabla_abc.ext" or "blabla_987123, rather than "555-123.ext"), you could literally translate the quoted definition to a regular expression, and get "123", by using `[0-9]` to match a digit and `[^0-9]` to match a non-digit. The latter serves the purpose of narrowing your digits down to the last ones present in the text, by stating that only non-digits may (optionally) succeed them.

E.g.:

`echo 234_blablabla_lololol_343999_blablabla_abc.txt | grep '[0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]*$' | grep '^...'`

**999**

Of course, there are many other ways to do this. For instance, grep has a `-P` flag to enable the most powerful kind of regular expression syntax it supports, namely Perl regex. With this, you can avoid a lot of redundant code.

E.g. with Perl regex, you can shorten repeats of the same regex unit ("atom"):

`[0-9][0-9][0-9]` -> `[0-9]{3}`

It even provides shorthands for common concepts as "character classes". One of these is "decimal digit", a shorthand for `[0-9]`, denoted as `\d`:

`[0-9]{3}` -> `\d{3}`

You could also use lookaheads and lookbehinds to fetch your 3 digits in one pass, alleviating the need of grepping for the first 3 characters afterwards (the `grep '^...'` part), but I can't be bothered to look up the particular syntax for that in grep right now.

Now sadly, I would have to think a lot how to generalize the above definition of "the last 3 consecutive digits that are not succeeded by a digit" into "the last 3 consecutive digits", meaning the above regular expression would not match file names where the last run of 3 digits is succeeded by a digit anywhere later in the file name, such as "blabla_12_blabla_123_blabla_56.ext", but I am optimistic that your naming convention does not allow that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bash` primitives to separate out the desired portion of the name.  There's probably a slicker way to get the binary conversion of the decimal number, but I like `dc`:

```
$ name=023-124.grf
$ base=${name%.*}
$ echo "$base"
023-124
$ suffix=${base##*-}
$ echo $suffix
124
$ echo "$suffix" 2 o p | dc
1111100
$ new_name="${base%%-*}-$(echo $suffix 2 o p | dc).${name##*.}"
$ echo "$new_name"
023-1111100.grf
```